# Windows 8 User Controls Sample

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Using the Windows 8 developer preview I'm trying to use a simple User Control I have created using the built in Windows Metro style template. 
As yet I have not been able to get my application to resolve the reference to the control even though it is in the same project and namespace as the page referencing it. I just get "The type was not found"
I've looked through the "Build" samples and could not find an sample C# project that uses a user control.
Does anyone know where I could find one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://asyncui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7969#139603

You can create a `UserControl` by right clicking your project and selecting Add/New Item (Ctrl+Shift+A) and selecting "User Control" from the list of item templates. You then name it and end up with the XAML that you can modify to add more UI like here:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Xyzzer.AsyncUI.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="768"
    d:DesignWidth="1366">

    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="#FF0C0C0C">
        <Grid
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="140">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="120" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button
                x:Name="BackButton"
                IsEnabled="False" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="PageTitle"
                Text="Some Page!"
                Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and code behind like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace Xyzzer.AsyncUI
{
    partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use that control elsewhere in XAML like this:

```
<xa:MainPage
    xmlns:xa="using:Xyzzer.AsyncUI" />
```

Comment: please add information to this answer to make it easier to understand. For me a compare with the previous version doesn't highlight any changes.

Comment: The original poster asked about a sample UserControl implementation and I linked to one that seemed to satisfy him at that time. I can add more details though.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the User Control is in the same namespace, you will have to declare the namespace to use it in the XAML.  Try adding the attribute to your page element

```
xmlns:uc="YourApplication.Namepace"
```

and the prefix to your XAML control

```
<uc:YourUserControl />.
```

Make sure that your project builds when you aren't referencing the User Control. An error in the user control will cause just this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default project template of the metro app, the namespace of the page is typically named as local, it's already in the new page created from template as following.

```
xmlns:local="using:App1"
```

Note the "using:" is new syntax in metro app.

So you can reference your user control as

```
<local:MyUserControl1/>
```

If you drag the MyUserControl from toolbox to the xaml designer, all these are automatic.  You don't need to write any code for this.